# Loading templates in a single file for backbone / underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, templating

I have a backbone application, which is served by a symfony2 server.

I have many backbone views and each has several templates that are rendered at different times using underscore's templating engine.

**I am trying to figure out how to serve the underscore templates to the client with maximum efficiency.**

Up until now I've written all of the templates in twig, and then rendered them as inline script tags to the response HTML during the initial request. This resulted in a long response time from the server during the first time a user enters my application.

**output example:**

```
<html>
<head>
   ...
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/template" id="template1">
        <div class="example">
            <%= someparam %>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/template" id="template2">
        <div class="anotherExample">
            <%= otherparam %>
        </div>
    </script>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

**Alternatives**

Now I'm looking for a better way to load these templates. perhaps by getting them in a second request in a single file, like an external JS file. But with anything I've tried, I have found it difficult to either access individual templates (like referencing them by id) or to keep them all in an efficient structure (in a single file, and without too much string manipulation or too many http requests).

### TL;DR

**How would one load many underscore templates?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider the JST approach, which is to concatenate the templates into a single javascript file. The pattern is described in [this Backbone Patterns tutorial](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#jst_templates).

I'm not familiar with Symfony/Twig, so I don't know if there is any tooling available. Based on your question I would guess it's easy to use your existing tools to render the templates into a javascript file instead of the HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

I think better way for you - it's precompile template, try to use [jsttojs](https://github.com/kupriyanenko/jsttojs), it will help you get single file with all you templates.

for example, from command line

```
jsttojs templates compiled/templates/index.js --ext mustache --watch
```

or use solution for grunt, [grunt-jsttojs](https://github.com/kupriyanenko/grunt-jsttojs)